# Django on Heroku can't connect to Postgres with different schema

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, schema

I devoted today to migrating my app from my local environment to Heroku.  It's been frustrating and fun at the same time, but now I'm very stuck.

I have a schema called `DCPViews` which I want the DB connections to default to when running queries.  I've read all the relevant tutorials / posts / tips and here's where I am:

**DB hierarchy**

```
postgres (default system database) 
  -> DCP (app database) 
    -> DCP (base tables schema) 
    -> DCPViews (views layer schema)
```

**settings.py**

```
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

...

DATABASES = {}

# DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>?currentSchema=<schema>'
DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://' + \
                config('DB_USER') + ':' + \
                config('DB_PASSWORD') + '@' + \
                config('DB_HOST') + ':' + \
                config('DB_PORT') + '/' + \
                config('DB_NAME') + \
                '?currentSchema=' + config('DB_SCHEMA_NAME')

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL, ssl_require=True)

...

# Configure Django App for Heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

### The problem

I've tried everything to get Heroku to use the correct DATABASE_URL (with `currentSchema` = `DCPViews`), but no luck.  I don't have DB permissions to create new roles nor set a search path for Heroku's default DB user.  It also won't let me export `DATABASE_URL` manually and doesn't seem to accept the value I pass in the `settings.py` file.  The `heroku config -s` command always returns the same `DATABASE_URL` value.

Everything works fine in my local environment, but this is a major snag.  How can I get Heroku to use the correct `search_path` or default to the `DCPViews` schema when running queries?

### Update

I'm send send the DB credentials and `currentSchema` I want to use in my `settings.py` file, but Heroku seems to ignore them and overwrites them when it creates the `DATABASES['default']` key.  Here's the Django debug when I load a page in my browser:

```
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'HOST': '<host_name>',
             'NAME': '<db_name>',
             'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': 5432,
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': '<user_name>'}}
DATABASE_URL    
'postgres://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>?currentSchema=<schema>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was on the right path.  I added the `search_path` to the ROLE and that did the trick:

```
ALTER ROLE <role_name> SET search_path = <go, pirates>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet, but since your settings file is using an environment file, you can just go to your heroku app in `heroku.com` and go to your database that is connected to your app. Then go to settings and click `reveal config vars`. Change your `DATABASE_URL` to whatever your need it to be (mind you it wil probably be just an extension off of your actual heroku postgres database url)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried and it won't let me change the `DATABASE_URL` value.  The Heroku documentation says it will update the `DATABASE_URL` value periodically anyways, so I'd also have to change it every time.

Comment: Ah yeah that's right. It does update so you can't do that. Is your current plan the free plan?

Comment: Yes, it's the free one.

Comment: Ah okay. Well if upgrading it to the first tier solves your problem that would be highly ideal. I am running a multi tenant app on that level with django/postgres and it is very cheap. Edit: Upgrading to utilize a database search path.

Comment: @OhGreatOne your answer looks aweasome. Please can you tell us the correct settings to run multitenancy con Heroku? I cant do that. I get a msg: " AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'set_schema" when run migrate_schemas --shared. I would really appreciate your help.